# Game Center view cut off on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, size, game-center, mainwindow

I'm updating an older project to support the iPhone/iPod 5's 4 inch screen. I've added the Default-568h@2x.png to my project, and almost everything seems fine, except:

- the Game Center overlay (view controller) is cut off at the bottom. [image: Game Center overlay cut off]
- Tweet sheet popups aren't full width.
- Touch input isn't being received on the right/bottom side of the screen.

Seems like my window isn't the correct length.

(I'm going to propose a solution, but I'd like some feedback as to whether or not this is a safe (or "correct") solution.)

Answer (score 1):

I've manually edited my MainWindow.xib file, changing the NSFrameSize from {320, 480} to {320, 568}, which has solved the apparent problem.

This doesn't seem to be causing problems on older/smaller screens, but I'm wondering if this is the best across-the-board solution...

Comment: I think I've found a better solution: checking the "Full Screen at Launch" box in the attributes of the Window in my MainWindow.xib. Same effect and seems more general / forward compatible. (This also follows Apple's recommendation in the docs at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html)

Comment: Thank you! You should change this comment into an answer and accept it! (I'm updating an app that hasn't been updated for 6 years)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you get the current screen size as in the height using following and then use it
instead of changing it manually

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

Comment: Indeed, screenRect will have the correct dimensions (ie. 1136 on the iPhone 5, even if I have the NSFrameSize set to 480), but I'm not sure how to use that information with my code architecture. Specifically, I'm using (an adapted version of) the sample EAGLView class here: (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLES2Sample/Listings/Classes_EAGLView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009188-Classes_EAGLView_m-DontLinkElementID_4) which receives initWithCoder when unarchiving the nib file. Although the bounds seem correct at that point (1136), the underlying window does not.

Comment: self.view.bounds.size.height = screenHeight//thats all you need to do  post your code if you want

Comment: Are you saying I should do this in the initWithCoder method of my EAGLView class? (because self.view isn't a property and modifying self.bounds in that method has no effect.)